# Making bootable usb in Mac OS 9?

Tags: installation, boot, usb, live-usb, mac

So I have an old G3 imac with mac os 9.2 and mac os 10.1.5  installed on it. I would like to use this computer to make a bootable ubuntu usb stick. However when I followed the instructions for using terminal in os x,it did not work.I dont know if the computer is just too old. I am new to linux. Is there any way that I can use this computer to create a bootable usb?

Comment: Have you followed the [instruction](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) on ubuntu.com? Can you tell us which steps didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this thread has the answer you are looking for:

[can't make bootable usb on mac](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228552/cant-make-bootable-usb-on-mac)

Looks pretty straight forward.