# Convert and ubuntu.iso file into a .dmg file

Tags: boot, system-installation, mac, iso

Can anyone help me figure out how to convert an iso into a dmg file..  I'm sure it has something to do with the dd command,  but I'm really not sure how to go about it..  I need to make a bootable ubuntu disk for an imac, and it is not reading any of the hundreds of burnt iso disks i have..  I'm at a total loss..  everything i can find about the process is done on a mac, and since my imac has been broken for about a year, I'm kind of stuck..

Thanks in advance.
Max

Comment: Have you tried:

`dd if=/path/to/file.iso of=/path/to/newfile.dmg`

Comment: No.. `dd` just copies a file.  .dmg is a mac hard disk image format that has headers translating bits of the file to bits of the virtual disk, with large holes of virtual disk that have no data stored in the file.  It is a totally different format and asking to convert one to the other makes no sense.

Comment: Working on a bootable disk for an old mac myself over here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/691996/how-do-i-burn-a-bootable-install-disk-that-my-macbook-pro-can-read so I will be watching this Q&A too.